# Is there a way to emulate iOS to run App Inventor apps from my PC?

Tags: ios, app-inventor

My teacher let us work with app inventor 2 for iOS devices, but the thing is that I don't have one so I was wondering if there was a way to install an iOS emulator for my PC (something like the emulator that opens from android in the desktop app inventor version)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to install simulators on Windows. You may consider [hackintosh](https://hackintosh.com/).